A point is in $\operatorname{Ext}A$ if and only if it has a neighborhood contained in $X\setminus{A}$
I would like to get some feedback on this prove.
We define
$\bar{A}$ = $\bigcap${$B\subseteq{X}$:$A\subseteq{B}$,$B^c \in T$} where $T$ is a topology on $X$
$\operatorname{Ext}A$ = $X \setminus \bar{A}$
So
\begin{align}
x\in\operatorname{Ext}A &\iff x\in\bar{A}^c \\
&\iff x \in \bigcup\{B\subseteq X: A\subseteq B, B^c \in T\}^c \\
&\iff x \in \bigcup\{B\subseteq X: A\not\subseteq B \text{ or }B^c \not\in T\}\\
&\iff \exists U\subseteq X:x\in U,A\not\subseteq U\text{ or }U^c \not\in T
\end{align}
My doubt comes here, may I then derive from the last part that
$\exists U\subseteq X:x\in U,U\cap A=\emptyset ,  U \in T$
I think its wrong, because there's no reason to think that the set $U$ we derived it existed has those properties in particular, still, I don't know how to proceed from here. Thanks!

I cannot quite follow your proof.
The first line is fine; it is by definition.
In the second line, it seems(?) that you are applying one of de Morgans laws, but the notation seems strange. The object
$$\{B \subseteq X: A \subseteq B, B^c \in T\}$$
is a collection of subsets of $X$. What, then, does it mean to take its complement? If the complement is being taken in $\mathcal{P} (X)$ (which is the most reasonable explanation I can think of), then it is not true. What is true is
$$x \in X - {\rm Cl} A$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x \in \bigcup \{B \subseteq X: A \subseteq X - B, B \in T\}$$
In plain English, this statement is equivalent to "$x$ is contained in the union of all open sets whose complements are supersets of $A$". You can see that this is equivalent to "there is some open set containing $x$ that is disjoint from $A$", written symbolically as
$$\Longleftrightarrow \exists B \subseteq X: x \in B, A \cap B = \emptyset, B \in T$$

Thank you so much for the answer! Now I see it more clearly, I thought taking the complement of such a set would be negating its condintions, but I see it isn't the case.
